# sesiones en java jsp y servlets

Tags: java, html, jsp, session, jstl

tengo un pequeño y molestoso problema, he creado una pagina de catalogo donde se genera sesiones para las personas registradas en una base de datos, tenía el problema de darle a la flecha retroceder volvía nuevamente a la pagina anterior pero continuaba logueado, así que utilice un pequeño codigo para eliminar la cache , y cuando retrocedía salía que necesitaba recargar los datos nuevamente, pero cuando le daba a el boton load o cargar , la flechita curveada al lado de las 2 flechitas de adelante y atrás , me vuelve a cargar la pagina logueada nuevamente , aquí dejo imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException, IOException {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     //Aqui se almacenan tus elementos
     ArrayList<Cesta> elementos = (ArrayList<Cesta>) session.getAttribute("misElementos");
     //Para que al recargar la pagina siga mostrando el catalogo
     Listaproducto = dao.Consultar();
     String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
     if (elementos == null) {
         elementos = new ArrayList<>();
         session.setAttribute("misElementos", elementos);
     }
     switch (accion) {
         /*Sirve para validar los usuarios al momento de iniciar sesión*/
         case "InicioSesion":
             String valor = "";
             String usuarios = request.getParameter("usuario");
             String contraseña = request.getParameter("contra");
             Usuario us = new Usuario(usuarios, contraseña);
             //Logueo para administrador
             Administrador ad = new Administrador(usuarios, contraseña);

             if (usuarios.substring(0, 4).equals("N000")) {
                 switch (Adao.Consultar_Admin(ad)) {
                     case "1":
                         HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
                         sesion.setAttribute("user", usuarios);
                         request.setAttribute("productos", Listaproducto);
                         request.getRequestDispatcher("/Administrador.jsp").forward(request, response);
                         break;
                     default:
                         valor = "error";
                         //La variable error toma el valor de 'valor'
                         request.setAttribute("error", valor);
                         RequestDispatcher rd = null;
                         rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Inicio.jsp");
                         rd.forward(request, response);
                         break;
                 }
                 break;
             } else {
                 switch (Udao.ValidarUsuario(us)) {
                     case "1":
                         HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
                         sesion.setAttribute("user", usuarios);
                         response.sendRedirect("Inicio.jsp");
                         break;

                     default:
                         valor = "error";
                         //La variable error toma el valor de 'valor'
                         request.setAttribute("error", valor);
                         RequestDispatcher rd = null;
                         rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Inicio.jsp");
                         rd.forward(request, response);
                         break;
                 }
                 break;

             }
```

Comment: Por lo que yo veo cuando le da a cerrar sesión tiene que llamar a ese mismo Servet, pero con una acción diferente a iniciar sesión. En esa acción deberás borrar o invalidar la sesion del usuario. Por último, redirigir al usuario a la página de inicio. Por último, si quieres que cuando llegue el usuario a la página de inicio se le cierre la sesión deberás comprobar en el JSP si tiene sesión activa, y si es así cerrarla.